# Typescript discriminant union with nested property with a long list of possibilities

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I read at a few places that discriminant unions from a nested property are not something feasible at this moment, or at least not without guard functions and I wanted to know if there's a way not to use guard functions at all to determine a type.

The goal is to try to use Enums for narrowing because multiple `CustomFieldType` can have the same type of `value`, and it would be simpler to register cases every time by using a switch statement rather than `if-elseif` to narrow down.

Here is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwmDOAXA9hAYgS2AGwCYBUBPAB2CgG8AoKGqASQDl8oBeKAcgxEXYBpraAZXwAlRgHFWHJACcuAcz4CaAWQCqAGXx1BAUQ26YzNuwhhsiDPBzAAxj360oeg0antr2Oz2VQA9H5QAArI8BgARhHYhFAAjAAMUMiIABbAMvCUAL6UuVyI6QBmAIa2ZHBIqJg4uABqxdhgwABCxdYAPMzAAB4FILjwsAgo6Fh4RKQAfBS+tsNVY7gAXDNOTogkwCv4ANy+OU4Abg1NK8UghHs5lPlFpeXzozX1jcB03FA9fQNDlU94LyarQ6FRG1XGmwAdIx8NMqEcTlsoOAIOF0lcbtw7mVfmDFoDgIJEHIQPJPr1QD9QQtnojgcB2tT-gQocIxAxxHDfMdXitZAoMbcZCUcUzwXVESpzJZBDZ7OTvoMxfi6W0GcqahNgJD1FodPpDLDVrQeadkZA0TIANoAXUFWOF91xNIBiNlXnlX0pSse4oJ9MZvsWWshLkNXIRvPNqPStoxlA2pGdzIJUg1rte70QUAAPsm-W7iQpc-mVa8pRYMO7vCX0xLXtX7LlCmAQPYMMgQFArFnxQAKWyFQ4rOsEgCUK0Hh27Pr+BczH3htBkwEQYBkXankLmc8WkMTZBYR9LmqhMOylBbbcsnZnRJJ8n7U5HQdprwnUCnM5PGaa9+LS40Cua4bp+Q7bq+eD7psrDHnWIZshIF5Xu2t5WBWMpyogT5Di+u5vk0H5flYP71k0GFVlhxpAau66buBO54jU0FJkebDwVCuraGGRjIa2qFdlYjbYYsA64aR46TkO36jm6VGAVAwF0WBhwQfhUEHrB7GQSypChgavHXLgdjYMUK6fp2SCfnhTG-sAuQBFAADqnbsNmIBmTIyAAO43IUUADmptm4Cxh5wTpIYwmO1GfpCppkI58ApMg5i4FAaLIp5PnAGlKDRpa2SfNg1jdv5gWMS6IWaWxpEIaIEjRQpthxYi-iBElKV4OlZAeTIXneTlUB5fypKFTgJUYGVzUVcyoVabVnGaNxBn4I1swta8bVQB1qXdZlfXZblyD5bGNoXpQjmCMgjQ3l23nnAUuAXYELkgG5+39Ze-G3VA8hNPA8BamJw4SYia1OPA3kYIgtgpAFW4zeKoXg2sNC2GqC16TCSy+KjNEgfRqnxVtO1dRlvX9YNeUogVeOfhjHF6YhHI43TThKaBW7E4lyW7eTWUDUd21FqNdPoyVjPalx+quPgrN4+LDzqbp2o8XLuN4xzhMbU0JO82TPUC1Tx006dGs0MZJTSisqT9ciwDeVAugHTIfZjvs52OQwAuDKQwreNEUCALwbgCyO1914dl2f3AADWpOdDKTiGAZm4MDNmVeOMWTQFPbcDhhxjijqNaypOsJYE7yFOkK5pW0J0yMHYdOActDZ32Qki4+olToXMXs7RnPgdzFcgFXfWDXXI1kqHHtOG36HSpRHoiTUwO9wp-cE6Xw-0KP1cT4MpvWjajez63ZVCVh+fr+bikD9rO+V-vteHxap2n83vi2z59uO87Xmu2io5No1gZDuWAIcdI2QgA%5D) that tries the different possibilities.

```ts
enum CustomFieldType {
    INT = 'int',
    STRING = 'string',
    MULTISELECT = 'multiselect',
    SELECT = 'select'
    // Possibly 20 others
}

interface CustomFieldValueBase<T extends CustomFieldType> {
    customField: {
        type: T;
    }
    value: any;
}

interface CustomFieldValueInt extends CustomFieldValueBase<CustomFieldType.INT> {
    value: number;
}
interface CustomFieldValueString extends CustomFieldValueBase<CustomFieldType.STRING> {
    value: string;
}
interface CustomFieldValueMultiSelect extends CustomFieldValueBase<CustomFieldType.MULTISELECT> {
    value: number[];
}
interface CustomFieldValueSelect extends CustomFieldValueBase<CustomFieldType.SELECT> {
    value: number[];
}

type CustomFieldValue =
  | CustomFieldValueInt
  | CustomFieldValueString
  | CustomFieldValueMultiSelect
  | CustomFieldValueSelect


// Solution wanted
// Won't narrow
function guessType(cfv: CustomFieldValue) {
    switch (cfv.customField.type) {
        case CustomFieldType.INT:
            return cfv.value // should be narrowed to number
        case CustomFieldType.STRING:
            return cfv.value // should be narrowed to string
        case CustomFieldType.MULTISELECT:
        case CustomFieldType.SELECT:
            return cfv.value // should be narrowed to number[]
        default: throw new Error()
    }
}
```

Comment: "I read at a few places that discrimina[ted] unions are not something feasible at this moment" do you mean where the discriminant is *nested*?  [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) are a feature of TypeScript and are feasible as far as I know.  What specifically is not feasible, and where did you read this?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll rephrase it. I meant where the discriminant is nested